# How to best handle Future.filter predicate is not satisfied type errors

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I love how scala is type safe, but one runtime error I keep running into is

```
 Future.filter predicate is not satisfied
```

I can see why I am getting this error, just looking for advice on how to best work around this error and handle it gracefully or maybe I am doing this wrong?

```
val r: Future[play.api.mvc.Result] = for {
  account <- accountServer.get(...)
  if account.isConfirmed
  orders <- orderService.get(account, ...)
} yield {
  ...
}
```

If the account is not confirmed, I will get the above error.

I would have thought that since there is a potential for the filter to fail, that scala would then make the yield return value an Option.  No?

Comment: How can it return an Option, if you declared the result type to be `Result`?

Comment: `recover` the `Future` to produce a meaningful error. Shouldn't `r` be a `Future[Result]`?

Comment: @m-z yes I changed it to a future thanks.

Answer (score 23):

`filter` doesn't make sense for `Future` since the type system wouldn't know what to return for the `else` case, so it is unsafe to rely on it (by using an if-guard). But you can do this within a for-comprehension to achieve the same thing:

```
val r: Future[play.api.mvc.Result] = for {
  account <- accountServer.get(...)
  orders <- if (account.isConfirmed) orderService.get(account, ...) 
            else Future.successful(Seq.empty) 
} yield {
  ...
}
```

(as Jean Logeart's answer, but within a for-comprehension)

Comment: How about conditionally transforming the successful `accountServer.get` to a Failure? Any potential downsides to that approach?

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to use a simple `flatMap` in which you can specify an `else` case:

```
val orders = accountServer.get(...)
                          .flatMap { account => 
                            if(account.isConfirmed) orderService.get(account, ...)
                            else Future.successful(Seq.empty)
                          }
```

Comment: But I want to handle this in a for-comp because I am using them allot currently.  Or is it just not possible?

Answer (score -1):

A [for-comprehension is just syntax sugar](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) for a chain of `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc.. When you write `if account.isConfirmed`, this is equivalent to using Future's `filter` method.

The value of a resolved Future is contained in a Try, which can either take the form of a Success or a Failure. (Compare this with Option, which can either take the form of Some or None.)

Much like Option's `filter` converts a Some to a None if the value contained fails the predicate, Future/Try `filter` methods will convert a Success to a Failure. If you look at the implementation for [Future.filter](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L334) or [Try.filter](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala#L253), this is done by returning a Failure with a `new NoSuchElementException` containing the `predicate is not satisfied` message you mentioned.

So, the error message itself is entirely by design, and consistent with the type system. Any step in the for-comprehension will only project another Future, so writing `if account.isConfirmed` will either project a Success if it passes the filter or a Failure if it does not.

This is the answer as to why Scala will not change the Future[Result] into Future[Option[Result]] when you use `if`/`filter`. If you would instead like to yield a successful Future containing Option or an empty Seq, you must do so explicitly (as seen in [Jean Logeart's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34572843/9537214) and [Alvaro Carrasco's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34583533/9537214) answers).